# Using Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") in IE7

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-7, adodb, .net-1.1

I have an ASP.NET 1.1 application that uses the following code to write out a file in the response:

```
Dim objStream As Object
objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.open()
objStream.type = 1
objStream.loadfromfile(localfile)
Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.read)
```

This code is called by a pop up window that displays this file or gives a open/save dialog in Internet Explorer. The problem is, that it seems to work fine in IE6 but in IE7 the pop up opens and then closes without displaying the file. Any one know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have a code like this for download files from server:

```
strFilename = Server.MapPath("/App_Upload/" & strFilename)   

With Response
   .AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream")
   .AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFilename & ";")
    .WriteFile(strFilename)
    .End()
End With
```

Try if work in your case.

Answer (score -1):

So the images that are being served by Asp.Net are tiff files. And it says [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1113169/2332853.aspx#2332853) that IE7 doesn't display files with 4 letter extensions for some reason. I think I'll try to change it to 3 letters and see what happens.